# App no longer on the app store

Tags: iphone, applications, apple-store

I have an issue with an app. I was forced to update my ios and now I can't open my favorite music app because it's no longer on the app store. I don't need it anymore, it's okay, I'll find another app. But I had A BUNCH of songs on that app and I just want to open it for a couple minutes to just screenshot all my songs I had in there, and I can delete it then. I have the app on my home screen, but I can't open it, because it gives me two options - to delete it or to keep it, but then nothing happens when I press to keep it. Is there any way to open that app to just see my data? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the app's developer to see if there's a way to do what you want?

Comment: no, how can I find the developer?

Comment: Google the app name or see if that developer has more apps on the App Store.  If so, there's usually a link to the developers home page.

Comment: but the app name is simply 'playtube', so there are a lot of playtubes all over app store. is there any other way to find the app developer?